# How to implement AddDays function in Custom SQLite Dialect for NHibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

Please help if you can.

I am using NHibernate to connect to a Sql Server instance and all is well.  For my test application (integration tests), I need to use SQLite.  All of my tests are working except those which use DateTime.AddDays(n) to derive a date (DateTime) as part of the query.

For Sql Server, I have extended the MsSql2008Dialect and call

```
public class CustomMsSql2008Dialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public CustomMsSql2008Dialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction( "AddDays", new SQLFunctionTemplate( NHibernateUtil.DateTime, "DATEADD(day,?2,?1)" ) );
    }
}
```

and configure this with

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">«namespace redacted».CustomMsSql2008Dialect, «assembly name redacted»</property>
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and I think this works for the queries I've tested manually.  I have also created the required HQLGenerator

```
public class AddDaysGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public AddDaysGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[] {
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<DateTime>(d => d.AddDays(0)),
        };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql( MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor )
    {
        return treeBuilder.MethodCall( "AddDays",
                                          visitor.Visit( targetObject ).AsExpression(),
                                          visitor.Visit( arguments[0] ).AsExpression()
                                      );
    }
```

and registered same with

```
public class ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry() : base()
    {
        this.Merge( new AddDaysGenerator() );
    }
}
```

and configured this with

```
configuration.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<«namespace redacted».ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
```

I have tried to extend this to SQLite however with the following class:

```
public class CustomSQLiteDialect : NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect
{
    public CustomSQLiteDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction(
            "AddDays",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate( NHibernateUtil.DateTime, "date(?1, '+' || ?2 ||' day')"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and configured my test project with

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">«namespace redacted».CustomSQLiteDialect, «assembly name redacted»</property>
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Each test run produces

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
```

with stack trace

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.Process(IASTNode tree)
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process()
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary``2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary``2 enabledFilters)
NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase``1.GetEnumerator()
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I have many queries to test.

Is this a bug in SQLite?

Is this a bug in NHibernate?

Is this (likely) a bug in how I've implemented this?

Again, please help.

Comment: Are you having NH use `ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry` and not the default registry?

Comment: I was unable to set this in config using 
    linqtohql.generatorsregistry

Comment: I am unable to set this in config using 
`linqtohql.generatorsregistry`
as described in [link](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html)
Instead I added this using `configuration.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<«namespace redacted».ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();`

Now I get `System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.` at `NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)`

Is this still a problem with NHibernate/SQLite or my SQLite Date() syntax?  Anyone know?

TIA

Comment: I switched my test database to use SqlCE instead and wired up a custom dialect that inherits `NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect`.  I register "AddDays" to us `dateadd(day,?2,?1)` and specified this dialect in config.  I still get the same error.  I'm 99% sure I have the SQL syntax correct so suspect the error is elsewhere or a bug.

Can anyone who has done this successfully offer a suggestion for debugging this?

TIA

Comment: I have to add, since switching to SqlCE, I have tried using a named query.  Unfortunately, I need to use `GETUTCNOW()` which would work with real  MSSQL but not SqlCE.  
It seems no matter which way I turn, there is no working around this.